# Accessing the container from a gadget on Google Sites

Tags: javascript, rpc, google-gadget, google-sites

I'm writing a custom navbar Google Gadget for use on a Google Site. I need to access data in the gadget container (the site page): either the webspace object which contains the breadcrumb object or at worst - the DOM so I can get the page title.

The Google Gadgets API provides an [RPC](http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/reference/#gadgets.rpc_method_summary/%22RPC%22) class with methods that are designed for container-to-gadget communication. However it seems the container needs to register an RPC service for it to be accessible. I don't know if the Google Sites page does this or I need to find some other way.

Comment: me too.................